# dynamically add uitextfield in the uiscrollview in iphone

Tags: iphone

i have an array of some values and i want to dynamically create textfields for all the string objects inside the array and add it to the scrollview.. how to do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate the UIScrollView using something like this:

```
// NSArray *strings;
// UIScrollView *scrollView;
// NSMutableArray *textFields;

self.textFields = [NSMutableArray array];

const CGFloat width = 320;
const CGFloat height = 31;
const CGFloat margin = 0;
CGFloat y = 0;

for(NSString *string in strings) {
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, width, height)];
    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.text = string;

    [scrollView addSubview:textField];
    [textFields addObject:textField];
    [textField release];

    y += height + margin;
}

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, y - margin);
```

and handle changing the strings in the [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) methods.