# how to implement scrollview for dynamically created textfields and labels

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiscrollview

I am creating some 6 to 10 textfields dynamically and also some labels dynamically.I want to implement scroll view for this.how to do it?i have dragged a scroll view  and implemented below code in the ViewDidLoad method.Even i connected IBOutlet for scrollview.But nothing is working.

Can anyone tel me with sample where i can add all this textfields into a scrollview and when it exceeds scroll view limit it should be scrolled down to see the textfields.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

{

```
[self textField1];
[self textField2];

[super viewDidLoad];
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 800);
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(500, 800)];
```

}

// code for creating textfield dynamically using -(void)textfield function

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 250, 200, 35)];

 UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 300, 200, 35)]; 

UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 350, 200, 35)];

UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 400, 200, 35)];

   UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 450, 200, 35)];


   UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 500, 200, 35)];
```

Comment: hi please go through this link hope it will help you  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903665/dynamically-add-uitextfield-in-the-uiscrollview-in-iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Main View, add one Scroll View. After that inside the Scroll View add UIView as Subview.

Like This: MainView --> 
                       ScrollView --->
                                      SubView

Then in ViewDidLoad:

```
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 500);
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0, 480.0);
subView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0, 460.0);
```

After that add TextFields Dynamically inside the SubView, not in MainView.

Comment: i have added ScrollView in my Xib file in that i have added one UIView now i have created textfields dynamically that is by above code.so how to add textfields inside this and make it scrollable?

Comment: Once you define the TextFiled dynamically, you have to add these textfields inside SubView.                                                                   [subView addSubview:textField];

Answer (score 0):

Get my code from [here](http://www.4shared.com/file/CNyV3_YU/TestView_Keyboard.html). Im sure it will help

Answer (score 0):

After creating the textfields, add textfields to the scrollview.

```
[scrollview addSubview:textfield];
```